# How to update a column pertaining to MySQL table with values from another column in another table using inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Event table (initial) :

[image]

status table:

[image]

table ready_reason:

[image]

table delay_reason :

[image]

table spare_reason:

[image]

table down_reason :

[image]

**Required output**

[image]

So basically, I've to replace the values in the columns status code  and reason code in the event table with the corresponding values from the tables below.

I tried all sorts of permutation and combinations of inner joins. However, couldn't crack it. Would appreciate any insights.

My code to update status code column (didn't work) :

```
update event eve
set eve.status_code = sta.name
inner join status sta on eve.status_code = sta.status_code
```

Since reason_ code column in event table needs to be update using multiple table, I'm unable to come up with code for this one

Comment: Hint:  Use `JOIN` and don't change the table!  You would just generate what you need for your result set.

Comment: Are all those other tables filled with static data? One way to do it could be with CASE and hardcoding the values, not the most elegant way to do it but if this is a one time thing maybe it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the names to the code fields you could create a view.

The example below uses LEFT JOIN's on the reason tables, and then COALESCE's the reason names.

```
CREATE VIEW vwEvent AS
SELECT 
 ev.*, 
 COALESCE(st.Name, ev.`Status Code`) AS `Status Name`, 
 COALESCE(ready.Name, delay.Name, spare.Name, down.Name, ev.`Reason Code`) AS `Reason Name`
FROM `event` ev
LEFT JOIN `status` AS st ON st.`Status Code` = ev.`Status Code`
LEFT JOIN ready_reason AS ready ON (ev.`Status Code` = 'R'  AND ready.`Status Code` = ev.`Reason Code`)
LEFT JOIN delay_reason AS delay ON (ev.`Status Code` = 'D1' AND delay.`Status Code` = ev.`Reason Code`)
LEFT JOIN spare_reason AS spare ON (ev.`Status Code` = 'S'  AND spare.`Status Code` = ev.`Reason Code`)
LEFT JOIN down_reason  AS down  ON (ev.`Status Code` = 'D2' AND down.`Status Code`  = ev.`Reason Code`);
```

Then select from the view to get the status and reason names:

```
select EventId, Duration, `Status Name`, `Reason Name`
from vwEvent
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4e1f7b1a9f5bdbdd4001086199df5df)*

Well, I suppose you could use the view to update the table itself.
But that might not be the best idea.

```
update `event` ev
join `vwEvent` vw on vw.EventId = ev.EventId
set ev.`Status Code` = vw.`Status Name`,
    ev.`Reason Code` = vw.`Reason Name`
```

Comment: The question is for MySql but your answer is for Sql Server

Comment: Doh! Oh well, that was easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Do an update using LEFT JOIN on "reason" tables and COALESCE on the `name` column from those tables

```
UPDATE event e 
JOIN status s ON s.status_code = e.status_code
LEFT JOIN ready_reason r ON r.status_code = e.reason_code AND e.status_code = 'R'
LEFT JOIN delay_reason d ON d.status_code = e.reason_code AND e.status_code = 'D1'
LEFT JOIN spare_reason sp ON sp.status_code = e.reason_code 
LEFT JOIN down_reason do ON do.status_code = e.reason_code
SET e.status_code = s.name, e.reason_code = COALESCE(r.name, d.name, sp.name, do.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

use join for example i was use 2 table join from above you complete all table join with common column like below

```
SELECT * FROM Event table e LEFT JOIN status s ON e.status_code=s.status_code
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything, you still have to look at the content of the columns

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the values in your tables are static, following code can update base on [CASE-WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) in MySQL.

```
update event eve
set eve.status_code = (SELECT name from status_table WHERE status_code = eve.status_code), eve.reason_code =   CASE

WHEN eve.status_code = 'R' THEN (SELECT name from ready_reason WHERE status_code = eve.reason_code)

WHEN eve.status_code = 'D1' THEN (SELECT name from delay_reason WHERE status_code = eve.reason_code)

WHEN eve.status_code = 'S' THEN (SELECT name from spare_reason WHERE status_code = eve.reason_code)

WHEN eve.status_code = 'D2' THEN (SELECT name from down_reason WHERE status_code = eve.reason_code)
```